# SQl Update on Multiple Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
StartDate       Departmentid    DateID
Jan 2010        3               500
Febuary 2011    8               501
March 2012      2               503
April 2013      1               504
```

Update above where departmentID should have the values of DateID

above 2 columns are coming from different Tables:

```
StartDate is from [DatesAvaliable]
DepartmentID is from [Persons]
DateID is from [DatesAvaliable]
```

The query used to build it is the following:

```
select i.startdate,DepartmentID,i.id as DateID 
from persons p 
inner join substitutetable ppk on ppk.id = p.DepartmentID 
inner join DatesAvaliable i on i.id = ppk.DateAvaliableID 
where departmentID is not null
```

This Table **[substitutetable]** kind of makes a connection between the table, otherwise the records I get are not possible

***How can i write an update query to update the above records***

**Where i can replace the departmentID values with DateID?**

Comment: I am totally lost on what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results would probably help.

Comment: I added a sample data and select query, all i am trying is to get the `apply an update to replace the departmentID values with DateID`

Comment: Remove the `SELECT` from your query and replace it with `UPDATE SET departmentID = DateID` your logic below will still grab the same results.

Comment: I'm completely lost here, too. Replace the departmentID values with DateID? The department ID should point to a row in a department table, whereas the date ID points to a row in the date table. If you replace the value of a department ID with a date ID, then either this will crash because there exists no department row with such an ID or it just points to some row that happens to have this same numeric ID. That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Your data sample doesn't help either. You are showing three columns and four rows. What is this data? Are these rows in the person table? And you want to change the stored rows, so different data is stored? Please show: 1) sample rows of the person table before the update. 2) sample rows of the date table. 3) the sample person table rows you'd expect after the update.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm following this correctly, which is confusing to begin with...

But if your select statement gets you what you need, then just turn your `select` statement into an `update` statement.

```
select i.startdate,DepartmentID,i.id as DateID 
from persons p 
inner join substitutetable ppk on ppk.id = p.DepartmentID 
inner join DatesAvaliable i on i.id = ppk.DateAvaliableID 
where departmentID is not null
```

** UPDATE **

```
Update P
Set DepartmentID = i.id
from persons p 
    inner join substitutetable ppk on ppk.id = p.DepartmentID 
    inner join DatesAvaliable i on i.id = ppk.DateAvaliableID 
    where departmentID is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [cte](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/) (common table expression)

```
with cte as
(select p.departmentid,i.id from persons p 
    inner join substitutetable ppk on ppk.id = p.DepartmentID 
    inner join DatesAvaliable i on i.id = ppk.DateAvaliableID 
    where departmentID is not null)
update cte set departmentid=id;
```